# Shell navigation reuses previous page in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, maui, tabbar, maui-shell

I have a .NET MAUI app that uses a database and a shell tabbar for page navigation.

One of pages, "Clients", shows data from the database and be loaded every time the page is displayed.

I had an issue where when I move around pages on TabBar, the data retrieved from database kept stacking up on previous results on the "Clients" page every time I visit there.

I was able to solve this issue by adding this code that I found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9300#issuecomment-1416893792):

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ShellContent _previousShellContent;

    protected override void OnNavigated(ShellNavigatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnNavigated(args);
        if (CurrentItem?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem is not null &&
            _previousShellContent is not null)
        {
            var property = typeof(ShellContent)
                .GetProperty("ContentCache", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);

            property.SetValue(_previousShellContent, null);
        }

        _previousShellContent = CurrentItem?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem;
    }
}
```

Then, I added a subpage "NewClientPage" that branches off this "Clients" page and is navigated with

`ClientsPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private async void AddClient_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
   await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("NewClientPage");
}
```

`App.xaml.cs`:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("NewClientPage", typeof(NewClientPage));
```

and goes back to "Clients" page with `GoToAsync()` (did not use built-in go back button because it did not work as I expected).

And now, It has the same issue of reusing previous page contents after going to `NewClientPage`, coming back to `ClientsPage`, and going to other page on TabBar.

For example,

1. MainPage --> 2. ClientsPage --> 3. NewClientPage --> 4. ClientsPage --> 5. MainPage, --> 6. ClientsPage

where `MainPage` and `ClientsPage` are on a TabBar.

Right after coming back from NewClientPage at 4, ClientsPage looks good. However, if I go to other page and come back, newly loaded data is displayed under the previous page content as duplicates.

This is the code that loads the page. Referred to this [video](https://youtu.be/Jd05P1jy_C4?si=FRoePuI8yWari1hK).

`ClientsViewModel.cs`:

```
public partial class ClientsViewModel : ObservableObject
{ 
   private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

   public ClientsViewModel(DatabaseContext context)
   {
     _context = context;
   }   

   public async Task LoadClientsAsync()
   {
     var clients = await _context.GetAllAsync<Client>();

     if (clients is not null && clients.Any())//if we have at least one client
     {
             Clients ??= new ObservableCollection<Client>(); //if null, initialize

             foreach (var client in clients)//insert each client into a obervable collection Clients 
             {
                 Clients.Add(client);
             }
      }
   }
}
```

This is called in OnAppearing().

`ClientsPage.xaml`:

```
 public partial class ClientsPage : ContentPage
{
  private readonly ClientsViewModel _viewModel;

  public ClientsPage(ClientsViewModel viewModel)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel;
    _viewModel = viewModel;
  }

  protected async override void OnAppearing()
  {
    base.OnAppearing();
    await _viewModel.LoadClientAsync();
  }
}
```

When I debug, `OnNavigated` seems to be running, but there is still previous data left after using GoToAsync.
When I'm on the `NewClientPage`, `CurrentItem?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem.Title` is Client. I'm guessing there is something wrong when `_previousShellContent == CurrentItem?.CurrentItem?.CurrentItem` like `Clients(on ClientsPage) == Clients(actually on NewClientPage)`, but I am not sure. I'm testing on Android.

How could I fix this?

[Code snippets](https://github.com/ch1h0kd/ReproductionShellNavigationBug) to reproduce the bug.

Comment: where is the code that actually loads the data in the page?

Comment: @Jason I've just added it.

Comment: OnAppearing will fire every time the page appears.  You either need to clear the collection first, or check if an item exists before adding it

Comment: @Jason There is no duplicate in the collection. If I add one thing, the size of the collection would be always one. I confirmed this by printing "clients.LongCount()". The issue is it does not create a brand new page when the page is visited, so it'll show the result of the loading on the previous page. So if it is the third time visiting the page with one element in the collection, there would be three duplicates on the screen.

Comment: How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem or more code snippets so that we can try to reproduce this problem on our side?

Comment: I'm working on it

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Code snippets are added.

Comment: I noticed that you missed uploading some code, such as the `.sln` file.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I uploaded it. Is there anything else missing?

Comment: You also missed file `test.csproj`.

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT There's `test.csproj` uploaded

Comment: Sorry, I still can't load your app correctly. I tried to create a new demo and copy your code, but the code still got some errors.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Now it should be ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by registering "NewClientPage" as `<ShellContent>` outside of `<FlyoutItem>` instead of using `Routing.RegisterRoute`.

Now I have `Shell.Current.GoToAsync(//ClientsPage);` for page navigation.

In AppShell.xaml

```
 <TabBar>
   ...
 </TabBar>
 <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:NewClientPage}" Route="NewClientPage">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clear the data before loading data again with code:

```
 Clients.Clear();
```

Please refer to the following code:

```
public partial class ClientsViewModel : ObservableObject
{      

      public async Task LoadClientsAsync() 
        {
            await ExecuteAsync(async () =>
            {
                var clients = await _context.GetAllAsync<Client>();
                Console.WriteLine("length = " + clients.LongCount());

                if (clients is not null && clients.Any())//if we have at least one client
                {
                    Clients ??= new ObservableCollection<Client>(); //if null, initialize
                   
                   //clear data before adding data again. 
                    Clients.Clear();


                    foreach (var client in clients)//insert each client into a obervable collection Clients 
                    {
                        Clients.Add(client);
                    }
                }
            }, "Fetching clients...");
        }
}
```